# A quite short riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am and I do;
>
> I learn where I group;
>
> Though my honesty is boo'ed,
>
> But hey, when cooked I'm good!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am and I do;

> I am a fish.  I do fish for fish.

I learn where I group;

> Fish group in schools.

Though my honesty is boo'ed,

> <strike>Is this a fishing boo ghost reference from Super Mario?</strike> ;)
> This part of your riddle is a little fishy to me.  At this point, I'm just fishing for the right answer.

But hey, when cooked I'm good!

> Some think so.

Comment: You got the answer :D  Can you figure out some better reasoning for the third line?

Comment: Yeah, and also some websites do *that* too. You'd better put it in spoiler-ified section.

Comment: Idea: GHOST FISHER!!!

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind at first haha "Boo'ed"

Comment: Haha, i think this sounds better than my original idea XD  I was thinking about fishy and phishing.

Answer (score 0):

I am and I do

> I am a cow and I can move around

I learn from my group

> Cows are in a group and learn from each other

Though my honesty is booed

> Beef is marinated in alcohol

But hey, when I'm cooked I'm good

> When the beef is cooked, it tastes good

Comment: Nice try, but this is too stretchy and straightforward :)